# I Edited AppDelegate.m to listen to port 8080 but it still fails because 8081 is in use

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

I'm setting up react-native with xcode. Port 8081 is hogged by a process that must stay there, so I want the packager to use port 8080 instead. I followed facebook's instructions found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html) but still get the error "port 8081" is already in use. Why is react native still trying to use port 8081 after I edited AppDelegate.m?

Below is the AppDelegate.m code with the commented parts removed:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;


  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/index.ios.bundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
  moduleName:@"amapp"
  launchOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Show us your AppDelegate.m file please. Have you restarted the packager as well?

Comment: @cutemachine  - I think so? I closed the terminal, opened a new one and ran react-native start. I even rebooted my machine. Maybe not though, this is my first time using react-native... When I started the packager in the new terminal it gave me: error: packager can't listen on port 8081 so maybe it was never restarted.

Comment: @HelloWorld did you manage to resolve this in the end? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is an open issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 10/25/2015, this appears to be an open issue over in the React Native project:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3330

I got it to work by doing a global find/replace from 8081 to a new port (8082 in my case). Ugly, but it worked.

This isn't really a solution, but it's the best workaround I found. Assuming you're using OSX:

```
cd myproject
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' {} \;
```

Comment: You are correct. I ended up just caving and moving my other project to port 8080. I like your workaround though - ugly but creative

Comment: I have to admit that the creativity was not mine - a coworker suggested it and I figured I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache in your xcode project.
command+shift+k

Comment: I did that too with no luck.